# How do you replay KahaDB message archives?

Tags: activemq-classic

In the ActiveMQ KahaDB documentation, it mentions that you can archive KahaDB data files so they can be replayed if needed later. Yet, through some searching and looking through their documentation and the draft copy of *ActiveMQ in Action*, I can't find any example or clues how to actually do the replay of those files.

I'm hoping someone out there can point me in the direction on what needs to be done in order to actually perform a replay.

Answer (score 1):

KahaDB only replays messages/events when a broker is started to return the broker to the state prior to the broker being stopped (recovering persistent messages, etc.)

It does not retain historical messages to be replayed on demand.  Once a message is dequeued successfully, then its removed from the KahaDB data files.

If you have such a requirement to copy messages for auditing/reuse, then I suggest look into something like [mirrored queues](http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html) or using the [camel wire-tap](http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html) pattern.